# C++: cannot convert 'float (*)()' to 'float'

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and today I started using functions.
When I try to compile the code I recieve this error message:

> 34|error: cannot convert 'float (*)()' to 'float' for argument '1' to
>   'float calculator(float, float, char)'|

Where is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Insert number
float ins_num(){
    float num;
    cout<<"Insert a number: ";
    cin>>num;
    return num;
}

//Insert operator
char ins_oper(){
    char oper;
    do{
        cout<<"Insert the operator: ";
        cin>>oper;
    }
    while(oper!='+'&&oper!='-'&&oper!='*'&&oper!='/');
    return oper;
}

//Calculator
float calculator(float n1,float n2,char oper){
    switch(oper){
        case '+':return n1+n2;
        case '-':return n1-n2;
        case '*':return n1*n2;
        case '/':return n1/n2;
    }
}

int main(){
calculator(ins_num,ins_num,ins_oper);
}
```

Comment: Should be `calculator(ins_num(),ins_num(),ins_oper());`

Comment: Which line gives that error?

Comment: @AndyProwl should be posted as answer.

Comment: @Axel: For a newbie, I felt I should have also explained why, what is the syntactic difference between a function pointer and a function call, explain what the compiler's error message meant, and so on. I was a bit lazy to do all of this :-)

Comment: +1, relevant, complete, concise code, error message, clear question. Why was this downvoted? Yes, the error is trivial but the error message, you have to admit, is **hellishly** confusing (if you’re new to programming).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Agreed. The only detail left out by the OP is which line actually causes the error.

Comment: Now guys you stop here. I can't believe this question is getting upvotes.

Comment: @H2CO3 ??? It’s a good question, well asked. Most beginners have tremendous problems understanding which information is relevant in a question. This question is definitely a positive exception. I’m actually quite upset that you’d think otherwise. A little humility is appropriate from time to time.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Have you asked a question like this on StackOverflow? If so, you're right. If not, that proves that it's not necessary.

Comment: @H2CO3 I’ve been programming for over a decade. When I began programming I’ve asked tons of questions worse than this one. And you did too.

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree with Konrad. An error message that contains function pointer syntax is *very* confusing to a beginner. This question is very well written and contains the information which is important in order to answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
calculator(ins_num, ins_num, ins_oper);
```

This calls the `calculator()` function with the `ins_num` and `ins_oper` **functions themselves** as arguments (of which the type is `float (*)()` and `char (*)()`, a pointer to a function returning `float` or `char`, respectively, and taking no arguments). You don't want that. You want to call the `calculator()` function with the **return value** of the other functions, so you should *call* those as well:

```
calculator(ins_num(), ins_num(), ins_oper());
```

And here's [some food for thought](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=decl#ptrfuncinit) on function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

To execute the code in a function, you need to use what programmers refer to as a *function call*. In C++, we do this with parentheses. So, at the very least, you need to change

```
calculator(ins_num,ins_num,ins_oper);
```

to

```
calculator(ins_num(),ins_num(),ins_oper());
```

You need to be careful, though. In my opinion, you are doing too much in this single line of code. I suggest that you split it into several lines:

```
float lhs = ins_num(); // "lhs" is a common mathematical abbreviation for "left hand side"
float rhs = ins_num(); // "rhs" is a common mathematical abbreviation for "right hand side"
char oper = ins_oper();

calculator(lhs, rhs, oper);
```

The primary reason to do this is that it will help you track down errors as your programs become more complex.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for future projects!